# Unity3D C# - Text UI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following piece of code. I referenced the text component in the editor to no_lives. The gamemanager (singleton) is being instantiated a scene before. The debug.log() shows 5 in the console. But when I try to set the text I get that the reference is not set to an instance of the object. Why is that?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class level1_script : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text no_lives;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        no_lives = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        int lives_n = gamemanager.lives_f ();
        Debug.Log (lives_n);
        no_lives.text = lives_n + " x";
    }
}
```

Comment: `no_lives = GetComponent<Text>()` seems not to work

Comment: Are you certain that `Start()` was called before `Update` and that the GetComponent is actually setting a value to `no_lives`? Also `lives_n` needs to be converted to a string `lives_n.ToString() + " x"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you certain that `Start()` was called before `Update` and that the `GetComponent` is actually setting a value to `no_lives`?

If not then code defensively. Also `lives_n` needs to be converted to a string `lives_n.ToString() + " x"` or use a format.

```
void Update () {
    int lives_n = gamemanager.lives_f ();
    Debug.Log (lives_n);
    if(no_lives != null) {
        no_lives.text = string.Format("{0} x", lives_n);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

> But when I try to set the text I get that the reference is not set to
>   an instance of the object.

That's because when you do `GetComponent<Text>‌​()`, it will look for the instance of `Text` component on **the-same** GameObject your `level1_script` script is attached to.

You have two choices:

**1**.Attach `Text` component that GameObject your `level1_script` script is atached to then your current code should work.

**2**.If you already have the `Text` component attached to another GameObject, let's say an Object called *"MyText"*, use *GameObject.Find* to find *"MyText"* then perform `GetComponent` on it to get the `Text` component.

```
no_lives = GameObject.Find("MyText").GetComponent<Text>‌​()
```

Edit:

> Well, both Text and script are attached to the same object
>   prntscr.com/f7p7vx

It's likely attached to multiple GameObject and the other GameObject does not have the `Text` script attached to it.

Select the `level1_script` script, go to **Assets** --> **Find References in Scene** then remove the duplicated script from other objects.

Comment: Well, both Text and script are attached to the same object http://prntscr.com/f7p7vx

Answer (score 1):

As the script logs '5' in the debug log, it seems to me that the variable lives_n is used correctly.
My guess is that the component "no_lives" isn't filled (that's what is often causing the "reference is not set to an instance of the object" error)
I suggest that you try to add the script to the UI Text object in your scene, this way the script finds the "Text" component on that object.

It's important to know the differences between objects and components, because they're both essential parts of unity. Objects are "things" in your scene, like cubes, cameras and stuff like that. Components on the other hand are part of object and define the properties of that object. For example: a camera object has a camera component to make it a camera and to make it actually viewable by the user.
The GetComponent<>() method searches for a (in your case) Text component on the object the script is attached to.

Hope this helps!
(oh and don't forget to remove the script from the other object you've placed it on, in case this works. Otherwise you'll still get errors)